# The type SortExpression.SortDirection is not visible - Full Text Search in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have followed the example in Google App Engine [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Passing_Queries_in_a_Query_Object):

```
SortOptions sortOption = SortOptions.newBuilder()
    .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder()
        .setExpression("birthDate")
        .setLimit(1000)
        .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.DESCENDING)
        .setDefaultValueNumeric(0))
        .build();
```

But there's an error: `The type SortExpression.SortDirection is not visible`

Im using Eclipse IDE. What's the cause of the error?

Comment: Did yo try compiling it manually? SortDirection is a public enum, so you shouldn't have any problems. Also, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Try updating to the latest SDK, 1.7. The docs reference the latest SDK.

Comment: it's now working on SDK 1.7, and removed method `setLimit`